# AS3 custom mouse cursor -- regular cursor not hiding

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make the standard mouse cursor disappear when y > 85

```
    var myCursor: Sprite;

    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
   stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;



    function init() {
    if (y>85) {
Mouse.hide();                               // This would hide the standard cursor
    }

myCursor = new MyCursorClass();
myCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
myCursor.visible = false;

addChild(myCursor);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeaveHandler);
    }

    function mouseMoveHandler(evt: MouseEvent): void {
myCursor.visible = true;
myCursor.x = evt.stageX;
myCursor.y = evt.stageY;
    }

    function mouseLeaveHandler(evt:MouseEvent): void {
myCursor.visible = false;

    }
    init();
```

but it doesn't work.. and I don't know the reason why. Any help? I have an if statement that declares the standard mouse to be hidden when at a certain level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you are trying to hide the cursor when the MOUSE_LEAVE event is triggered, but you need to call the init function for every MOUSE_MOVE in order to check the if the Mouse.y is minor of `y`.

This could be useful for you:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeaveHandler);

var myCursor:Sprite;
myCursor = new MyCursorClass();
myCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
myCursor.visible = false;
addChild(myCursor);

function showCustomCursor(action:Boolean) {
  if (action) {
    Mouse.hide();
    myCursor.visible = true;
  } else {
    Mouse.show();
    myCursor.visible = false;
  }  
}

function mouseMoveHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
  myCursor.x = evt.stageX;
  myCursor.y = evt.stageY;

  // check for every mouse move event
  showCustomCursor(evt.stageY > 85); // if evt.stageY > 85

  evt.updateAfterEvent(); // Smoothing
}

function mouseLeaveHandler(evt:MouseEvent): void {
  showCustomCursor(false); // Show the default cursor
}

// Init
showCustomCursor(myCursor.y > 85);
```

Comment: You're welcome, If you think that is the correct answer, mark it as resolved please!!